# Howto CALayer's image scale independently of CALayer's bounds

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, touch

I can't find an answer for this one.

I would like to know how to have the image size in a calayer's to be lower than calayer's bound's size.

I've got several pawns in an iPad game, each is a CALayer and I have them resize simply with a contentsGravity=kCAGravityResizeAspect. Image is 128x128 inside of a CALayer of 30x30 so the image gets resized automatically to 30x30 and because of both being a box, aspect ratio maintains and works.

Here I set CALayer's bounds proportional relative to superview's size, so the Pawns always present the same relative size to the view. This one is inside my sprite class subclass of calayer:

```
-(void) setSpriteScaleToDice {
    CGFloat newSize = [self superlayer].bounds.size.width * 0.066666667f; 
    self.bounds=CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, newSize, newSize);
    self.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect; 
}
```

Note that in my case the CALayer bounds gets a maximum of 30x30 which is small for a touch. That's the problem I'm facing, due to this small size it's difficult to "touch" them, sometimes touch fails...

One of the ideas that I'm thinking is to increase the "bounds" of the calayer, while keeping the image at its original size. The problem is that I've search a lot and tried several options with contentsGravity, contentsCenter, contentsScale, etc... without success.

In particular, as per apple docs looks like the way to go is with contentsCenter (and not using contentsGravity), however I get deformation in the bitmap...

Please, any idea is really welcome, and thanks in advance,

Luis

Comment: Have you tried making the CGImage smaller than the bounds of the layer and using kCAGravityResizeAspect?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've tried that, the problem is that "sometimes" I need to increase the bounds to 128x128 and coming from a small original cgimage would loose a lot of resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a silly question, but why are you using `CALayers` for this instead of `UIViews`? `UIImageView` has a `contentMode` property that lets you do this easily (not to mention being easier to use for touch event handling).

That said, `CALayer` has a `contentsRect` property that appears to let you define a sub-rectangle for contents to be drawn within, so that may let you do what you want.

Another option would be to place your image layer inside a larger layer and use that for the hit test.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I finally decided to go the CALayer way which fitted perfect to handle sprites and texture atlas (probably uiviews also), and also I'm developing at the same time for cocoa and cocoa touch, so I went that way. Your second option (contentsRect) can't use it as I'm doing texture atlas. And your third recommendation is very interesting... I'll try it tomorrow and come back. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. I've finally go with the option of placing my image layer inside a larger layer and using both layers for hottest. Now it's working as expected. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

CAlayer CGFloat **contentsScale**

```
/* Defines the scale factor applied to the contents of the layer. If
 * the physical size of the contents is '(w, h)' then the logical size
 * (i.e. for contentsGravity calculations) is defined as '(w /
 * contentsScale, h / contentsScale)'. Applies to both images provided
 * explicitly and content provided via -drawInContext: (i.e. if
 * contentsScale is two -drawInContext: will draw into a buffer twice
 * as large as the layer bounds). Defaults to one. Animatable. */
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your image drawn in the CALayer at a size other than the CALayer you need to create your own `drawInContext:` method and draw the image rather than setting the CALayer's `contents` property. Do not set the `contents` property, create your own to track the image you want to draw.

Comment: Ok thanks for the recommendation. I'll test first Nick's option and then try this one. THanks again.

Comment: Overriding drawInContext will be quite slow I think - it uses Core Graphics for drawing instead of OpenGL, so it's not hardware accelerated.

Comment: @NickLockwood The system uses OpenGL (or Metal) only for composition (always when composing CALayers and CoreImage images but also for many composition operations of CoreGraphics) - it never uses OpenGL for any drawing operations (no matter what framework, no matter what system). If you draw a bitmap image to a bitmap drawing context, that is actually composition nowadays and not drawing and can easily done by the GPU. Drawing is when you draw text or lines or rects or ovals or gradients.

Comment: @NickLockwood And before someone complains, yes, Apple has written QuartzGL that can actually perform even "real drawing operations" on the GPU. It's part of the system since 10.4 and still it has never been enabled by default (you can enable it with Apple's CoreGraphics debug tool); it is said to be buggy (produces visual glitches), hence all drawing is still done by the CPU. I don't know if Apple even ported that part to iOS as well, I doubt it. If you ignore text rendering for a second, 90% of all UI today is not drawn anyway but composed.

Comment: @Mecki I don't think any of that contradicts what I said (which is that scaling/cropping images using the layer contents properties will be hardware accelerated, but cropping them manually by drawing them with core graphics inside drawInContext: won't be)

Comment: @NickLockwood Drawing an image to a CALayer may be a composing operation. CALayers are in fact textures in GPU memory, so Apple has two choices how to realize that draw: They can do in RAM and then re-upload the whole texture (no h/w accelerated), they can upload the image to the GPU and render it to the texture (h/w accelerated). The upload is a bit expensive as well but note that a CALayer will only re-draw it's content when `needsDisplay` is set on it or it is resized (when being covered and uncovered, the layer is recomposed to screen but with the cached content of the last draw call)